# How do I generate new workouts by clicking button in my application?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, frontend, project

I am trying to figure out how to make my application generate a new random workout every time I click the "Generate New Workout" button. I can't figure it out.

I realize my code is a mess, but this is what I've built so far and will be refactoring at some point.

I know it has to do with DOM; therefore, an "addEventListener" to list for the click is likely necessary, but I can't get my workouts to auto generate.

It will keep appending a new list of workouts one on top of the other on the same page instead of refreshing and generating just one new workout.

Thanks in advance.

```js
// Leg Exercise Variation
    let legs = ['Hack Squat', 'Leg Press', 'Back Squats', 'Leg Extensions', 'Lunges', 'Zercher Squat' ]
    
    let rLegs = legs[Math.floor(Math.random() * legs.length)];

    // Horizontal Press

    let hPress = [
      'Dumbbell Flat Press',
      'Machine Press',
      'Barbell Flat Press',
      'Dumbell Flat Press',
      'Chest Pullover Machine',
      'Pec Deck',
      'Pushups',
      'Weighed Dips',
    ]
    
    let rhPress = hPress[Math.floor(Math.random() * hPress.length)];

    // Horizontal Pull 
    let hPull = [
      'Barbell Row',
      'Tbar Row',
      'Dumbell Row',
      'Row Machine',
      'Bodyweight Inverted Row',
      'TRX Row'
    ]

    let rhPull = hPull[Math.floor(Math.random() * hPull.length)];

    // Vertical Press

    let vPress = [
      'Shoulder Press Machine',
      'Seated Shoulder Press',
      'Push Press',
      'Standing Overhead Press',
      'Assisted Handstand Pushup',
    ]

    let rvPress =  vPress[Math.floor(Math.random() * vPress.length)];

    // Vertical Pull 

    let vPull = [
      'Lat Pulldown',
      'Chinups',
      'Pullups',
      'Seated Vertical Pull Machine',
    ]

    let rvPull = vPull[Math.floor(Math.random() * vPull.length)];

    // Hinge/Hamstrings Variation

    let hinge = [
      'Hyper Extensions',
      'Deadlifts',
      'Kettlebell Swings',
      'Hamstring Curls',
    ]

    let rHinge = hinge[Math.floor(Math.random() * vPull.length)];

    // Carry/Grip
    let carry = [
      'Farmers Walk',
      'Barbell Holds',
      'Dumbbell Holds',
      'Plate Pinches',
      'Grip Machine'
    ]
    
    let rCarry = carry[Math.floor(Math.random() * carry.length)];

    // Bicep Isolation

    let biceps = [
      'Dumbbell Curls',
      'EZ-Bar Curls',
      'Cable Curls',
      'Barbell Curls',
      'Incline Dumbbell Curls'
    ]

    let rBiceps = biceps[Math.floor(Math.random() * biceps.length)];

    // Tricep Isolation

    let triceps = [
      'Skull Crushers',
      'Tricep Kickbacks',
      'Tricep Dips',
      'Tricep Machine',
      'Tricep Cable Extension'
    ]

    let rTriceps = triceps[Math.floor(Math.random() * triceps.length)];

    // Functional Cardio

    let cardio = [
      'Sprints',
      'Battle Ropes',
      'Rowing Machine',
      'Tire Slams',
      'Sled Drags',
      'Sled Pulls'
    ]

    let rCardio = cardio[Math.floor(Math.random() * cardio.length)];





    const myWorkout1 = [
      {'Exercise': `${rLegs}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': '10', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rhPress}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': '10', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rhPull}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': '10', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rvPress}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': '10', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rvPull}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': '10', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rHinge}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': '10', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rCarry}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': 'AMRAP', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rBiceps}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': '10', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rTriceps}`, 'Sets' : '3', 'Reps': '10', 'Rest':'2 minutes'},
      {'Exercise': `${rCardio}`, 'Sets' : '10', 'Sets': '8', 'Reps':'30 seconds AFAP', 'Rest':'1 minute'}
    ]

  buildTable(myWorkout1)
  
    function buildTable(data){
      const table = document.getElementById('myTable');
      

      for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        let row = `<tr>
                      <td>${data[i].Exercise}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].Sets}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].Reps}</td>
                      <td>${data[i].Rest}</td>
                   </tr>`
                   table.innerHTML += row;
      
      }
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
  <title>Fullbody Workout Generator | A Fullbody Workout Generator</title>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
    <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">Fullbody Workout Generator</span>
  </nav>
 <div>
  <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
    <tr>
      <th>Exercise</th>
      <th>Sets</th>
      <th>Reps</th>
      <th>Rest</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody id="myTable">

    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Generate New Workout</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, and `addEventListener` on the `button` - since it's the ONLY button, you could do `document.querySelector('button').addEventListner('click', fn)` ... where `fn` is the name of the function you want to call

Answer (score 0):

If you want the new list of workouts to show instead of appending to the existing list, make the following change in `buildTable()`. After getting the table element, clear whatever contents are inside before assigning new content.

```
table.innerHTML = ""
```

As for generating new workouts, attach an `onClick` handler on your button

```
<button class="btn" onClick="buildTable()">Generate New Workout</button>
```

Also, you will want to refactor how you generate a random workout. A new random workout (i.e. new random index for exercises) should be generated every time the user clicks the button, so you'll want to move that functionality into a function that `buildTable()` calls, instead of the current implementation -- which generates a random index *once* and uses that same index to determine which exercises to add to the table.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but I'm not sure how to go about fulfilling what you recommend in the last paragraph? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps in your `buildTable()` function you can call `generateRandomIndex()` which generates a random index for each exercise and then use that to build the table. This way, a new set of indices is generated every time the user clicks the button.